# JSTL c:import strange behaviour with xml file

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I'm trying to use c:import to import xml files for an XML transformation. I'm seeing strange behviour. When I try to import the xml files using relative references, I get non-interpreted JSP template files back in the variables.

Environment:  Tomcat 8.09, Spring 3, JSTL 1.2

This is my page definition and it works fine when the domain is added to the c:import:

```
     <%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%-- This is the side bar for the admin application --%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>

<tiles:importAttribute name="currentPage" />
<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/assets/xml/admin/shared/sideBar.xsl" charEncoding="UTF-8" var="xslt" />
<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/assets/xml/admin/shared/sideBar.xml" charEncoding="UTF-8" var="xml" />
<x:transform xml="${xml}" xslt="${xslt}">
    <x:param name="currentPage" value="${currentPage}" />
</x:transform>
```

But if I change the c:import to import relative links like this:

```
<c:import url="/assets/xml/admin/shared/sideBar.xsl" charEncoding="UTF-8" var="xslt" />
<c:import url="/assets/xml/admin/shared/sideBar.xml" charEncoding="UTF-8" var="xml" />
```

it breaks, and if I print out the values, I see a strange behaviour where the xml & xslt variables contain the JSP code from one of my tiles templates (but it's not populated). I can't explain why it's even trying to resolve a tiles template, I disabled security completely, and can hit each of those URL's no problem in a fresh browser window.

I would prefer to use relative links for portability, so can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify context in c:import if the files being imported are in *same context* as the file in which its being embedded. So for your application if *assets* is the context, then you can specify import as:

```
    <c:import url="/xml/admin/shared/sideBar.xsl" charEncoding="UTF-8" var="xslt"/>
    <c:import url="/xml/admin/shared/sideBar.xml" charEncoding="UTF-8" var="xml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but the assets context is relative to the application root. It's interesting though, is there a better way to store and reference the xml files relative to the webapp? Perhaps under WEB-INF? I only put them in the public domain because it's the only way I could figure to make it work, would be better to load them from internal to the web-app if I could...

Comment: Try it by placing under WEB-INF folder: <c:import url="/WEB-INF/sideBar.xsl" charEncoding="UTF-8" var="xslt"/>. But i doubt if it works without a streamreader.